# An unexpected problem in decomposition to prime factors - C

Tags: c, pointers

I wrote a program to decomposition numbers to prime factors:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    while (1 == 1)
    {
        printf("\n\tPlease enter the number: ");
        long long num;
        scanf("%d", &num);
        long long *const p;
        long long i = 2;
        int k = 0;
        while (num != 1)
        {
            if (num % i == 0)
            {
                *(p + k) = i;
                printf("num = %d and i = %d / ", num, i);
                num /= i;
                printf("num = %d and i = %d\n", num, i);
                k++;
            }
            else
            {
                if (i == 2)
                    i = 3;
                else
                    i += 2;
            }
        }
        printf("\t");
        for (int c = 0; c <= k; c++)
        {
            printf("%d", *(p + c));
            if (c != k)
                printf(", ");
        }
    }
}
```

For example, I enter the number 8 each time, it gives me a different answer every time, or it doesn't answer at all! That's why I put `printf("num = %d and i = %d / ", num, i);` and `printf("num = %d and i = %d\n", num, i);` in lines 17 and 19 for checking the variable `i`. Delivers strange numbers, it is interesting, then each time the run shows different numbers! I've run it two times with number 8:

```
        Please enter the number: 8
num = 8 and i = 140365918 / num = 4 and i = 70182959
num = 4 and i = 70182959 / num = -2147483646 and i = 35091479
num = -2147483646 and i = 35091479 / num = -1073741823 and i = 17545739
num = -1073741823 and i = 17545739 / num = -357913941 and i = 5848579  
num = -357913941 and i = 5848579 / num = 894919671 and i = 881
```

Second:

```
        Please enter the number: 8
num = 8 and i = 1932883282 / num = 4 and i = 966441641
num = 4 and i = 966441641 / num = -2147483646 and i = 483220820
num = -2147483646 and i = 483220820 / num = 1073741825 and i = 241610410
num = 1073741825 and i = 241610410 / num = 1789569707 and i = 80536803  
num = 1789569707 and i = 80536803 / num = -1360072977 and i = 16107360
num = -1360072977 and i = 16107360 / num = 285832897 and i = 37372
```

Of course, these two runs did not work out. But when we put `printf("%d\n",i);` before `if (num % i == 0)`, it shows a list of `i`s as I have defined it (2, 3, 5, 7, 9 ...). Of course, I guess there might be a problem with defining the array as a pointer, I'm new to pointers, but I can't justify that the variable `i` behaves differently inside and outside the `if` command.

Comment: 0th) turn on and mind your compiler warnings.

Comment: **ISSUE**: you're using `p` without having assigned it a valid value

Comment: Where does `p` point to?

Comment: p points where?

Comment: How can I setting p valid?

Comment: I set it as an array: long long *const p

Comment: No, that's just an uninitialized pointer. Use `malloc` or a real array.

Comment: You do not have any array in your code. The `array` tag was removed on purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple bugs in your program.

In comments it was already mentioned that you do not provide memory for `p` which causes undefined behaviour when you dereference that pointer.

You also have wrong format specifiers all over your program:

```c
    long long num;
    scanf("%d", &num);
```

There are 2 problems:
You use wrong format specifier. You provide a `long long` but only scan an `int`. This will fail scanning large numbers and more important it will leave parts of that variable without initialization.
Again this is undefined behaviour.
You also do not check the return value of `scanf` which is a must.

The correct conversion specifier for `long long` is `%lld`.

You make the same mistake when you print values:

```c
    printf("num = %d and i = %d / ", num, i);
```

Again, you tell the function to handle an `int` while the real argument is of type `long long`. In this case this will pass more bytes to the function than expected. As a result, `printf` will only print the first `%d` using part of the bytes from `num`. The excess bytes are then used to print `i= %d`. This will print the random bytes that were not initialized before. The bytes passed for `i` will never be touched by `printf`.
Again, this is undefined behaviour.

Your compiler should tell you some warning for each of these mistakes.
If you haven't done yet, enable warnings: For GCC use `-Wall -Wextra`.
And then read them and fix them.

Same error for printing. Your compiler should print some warning on those errors.